# Group by in pivoting in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot-table

This is just a part my stored procedure comes from a union select

```
DECLARE @sql AS nvarchar(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT CASE 
WHEN [Customer Posting Group] IN (' + '''INHE''' + ',' + '''INH''' + ',' + '''IN HOUSE''' + ') THEN ' + '''IN HOUSE''' + '
WHEN [Customer Posting Group] =' + '''GMA''' + ' AND [COMPANY]=' + '''JLC''' + ' THEN ' + '''JLC GMA''' + '
WHEN [Customer Posting Group] =' + '''GMA''' + ' AND [COMPANY]=' + '''NUDERM''' + ' THEN ' + '''NUDERM GMA''' + '
ELSE [Customer Posting Group]
END AS [Customer Posting Group]
,ISNULL([' + CAST(@PrevYear AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '],0) as [' + CAST(@PrevYear AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ']
,ISNULL([' + CAST(@YEARcurr AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '],0) as [' + CAST(@YEARcurr AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ']
FROM #tmpPERregion                        
PIVOT(SUM([GROSS AMOUNT])
FOR [MONTH YEAR] IN ([' + CAST(@PrevYear AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '],[' + CAST(@YEARcurr AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '])
) AS PivotSales'
```

The Result is

```
Customer Posting Group       2015                                 2016
 JLC GMA                2262533.000000                          2181239.500000
 IN HOUSE               0.000000                                  380.000000
 IN HOUSE               200.000000                              2940.000000
 LUZ                    241354.000000                           265481.500000
 MIN                    214083.500000                           95776.500000
 VIS                    315547.000000                           378649.000000
 NUDERM GMA             1588089.000000                          1991609.750000
 LUZ                    574094.000000                           717892.250000
 MIN                    120125.750000                           106789.000000
 VIS                    202294.500000                           258561.000000
```

I want my result to be `Group by` Customer Posting Group

Answer (score 0):

Try below one, syntactically might be wrong, you need to check for same.

```
SET @sql = 'Select   t.CustomerPostingGroup
                    ,ISNULL([' + CAST(@PrevYear AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '],0) as [' + CAST(@PrevYear AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ']
                    ,ISNULL([' + CAST(@YEARcurr AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '],0) as [' + CAST(@YEARcurr AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ']
            From    (
                        Select  CASE 
                                        WHEN [Customer Posting Group] IN (' + '''INHE''' + ',' + '''INH''' + ',' + '''IN HOUSE''' + ') THEN ' + '''IN HOUSE''' + '
                                        WHEN [Customer Posting Group] =' + '''GMA''' + ' AND [COMPANY]=' + '''JLC''' + ' THEN ' + '''JLC GMA''' + '
                                        WHEN [Customer Posting Group] =' + '''GMA''' + ' AND [COMPANY]=' + '''NUDERM''' + ' THEN ' + '''NUDERM GMA''' + '
                                        ELSE [Customer Posting Group]
                                END AS CustomerPostingGroup
                                ,Sum([GROSS AMOUNT]) As GROSSAMOUNT
                                ,[MONTH YEAR] As MONTHYEAR
                        From    #tmpPERregion
                        Where   [MONTH YEAR] In (' + @PrevYear + ',' + @YEARcurr + ')
                        Group By CASE 
                                        WHEN [Customer Posting Group] IN (' + '''INHE''' + ',' + '''INH''' + ',' + '''IN HOUSE''' + ') THEN ' + '''IN HOUSE''' + '
                                        WHEN [Customer Posting Group] =' + '''GMA''' + ' AND [COMPANY]=' + '''JLC''' + ' THEN ' + '''JLC GMA''' + '
                                        WHEN [Customer Posting Group] =' + '''GMA''' + ' AND [COMPANY]=' + '''NUDERM''' + ' THEN ' + '''NUDERM GMA''' + '
                                        ELSE [Customer Posting Group]
                                END
                                ,[MONTH YEAR]
                    ) As t
            PIVOT(SUM([GROSSAMOUNT])
            FOR [MONTHYEAR] IN ([' + CAST(@PrevYear AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '],[' + CAST(@YEARcurr AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '])
            ) AS PivotSales'
```

Comment: I already do that approach, Its not working it shows invalid column name after t.CustomerPostingGroup

Comment: May I have some sample of data ?